# jquery multiselect - checkbox for <optgroup>

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using a jquery multiselect plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ with  option. All works fine, however one of the client requirement is to have a checkbox in the  option. Does anyone know how to do this?

Te case is that I want to have the checkboxes in all options like here:

```
[] England <-This is <optgroup>
   []London
   []Leeds
   []Manchaster
```

so, "England" is the title for my  and I want it to also have a checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is your looking for and how it differs from what you have (or what is seen in the demos).

Comment: Did you see the [basic demo](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)?

Comment: So you want an `<optgroup>` to select or deselect all sub categories? Is that what you're going for?

Comment: select/deselect and I want to have a checkbox also. Client told me that in case there is NO checkbox in the <optgroup> he didn't know he can click on it and all subcategories will be selected. Therefore I want to have a checkbox here.

Comment: I think you'll need a widget that can specifically do this, this doesn't sound like anything that can be easily added to some existing widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this funcitonality is not available by default with the plugin you are using. If you want to add it, you will either need to hook into their events (I'd recommend the `create` and `optgrouptoggle` events), add it in manually to the source code (line 145 is what you're looking for in the non-minified version) and then also hook into their `optgrouptoggle` event and mark it checked, or file it as an [enhancement in their bug system](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues).

Comment: Thank you for an answer. It seems it's too hard task for me as I'm not fluent enough with js and jQuery

Comment: @niao I'd recommend filing it as a request in their bug system then. Not sure if or when they would get around to it, but having it in their system is better than nothing.

Comment: I know I shouldn't ask you, but is there any chance you can help me achieve the functionality as you described?